# How do I solve a None error in a translation website

Tags: python, html, django, translation

I am currently coding my first website, which is a translator in an invented language. You input a random phrase and it should get translated in the invented language.
Here's the code for the translation:

```
class TranslatorView(View):
    template_name=  'main/translated.html'
    def get (self, request, phrase, *args, **kwargs):
        translation = ""
        for letter in phrase:
            if letter.lower() in "a":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "U"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "u"
            elif letter.lower() in "t":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "A"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "a"
            elif letter.lower() in "c":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "G"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "g"
            elif letter.lower() in "g":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "C"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "c"
        return render(request, 'main/translator.html', {'translation': translation})
    def post (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.phrase = request.POST.get('letter')
        translation = self.phrase
        context = {
            'translation': translation
        }
        return render(request,self.template_name, context )
```

Template where you input the phrase:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

{% block content%}
<form action="{% url 'translated' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <center><h2 class = "display-3">TRANSLATE YOUR DNA CHAIN</h2></center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <textarea class="form-control" name='text' id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="6"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type='Submit' class= "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Translate</button>


    
      </div>   
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Template where the text should get translated:

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

{% block content%}

<div >
    <center><h2 class = "display-4">DNA TRANSLATED SUCCESFULLY INTO</h2></center>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <center>
        <h3>
        {{ translation }}
    </h3>
    </center>
       

    
</div>   

{% endblock content%}
```

Here's the thing, when I translate the phrase and redirects me to the translated template, this appears instead of the translated phrase.

[image]

As you can see, it appears a None.

I have no clue where the error is. If someone knows the error, please answer because i'm stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Name of your textarea is `text` and not `letter`

```
self.phrase = request.POST.get('text', 'default_value')
```

Also there is no point of setting attribute to object you can just use it as variable

```
phrase = request.POST.get('text', 'default_value')
```

Comment: Why should I write default_value?. I'm asking this just to improve my knowledge

Comment: Default value would be set if nothing is passed through form, it is not necessary if you expect user always to have this field

Comment: Okay, now it appears the line i wrote. Now what should I do to translate the text based on what i wrote in the get function